# MongoDB SELECT * GROUP BY

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am playing around with MongoDB trying to figure out how to do a simple

```
SELECT * FROM data GROUP BY userid
```

But I can't figure out how? I have a collection like

```
data=[{
    _id: "Kcs93S4R9v",
    userid: "KqDuEwgv",
    time: 1584353953159,
    content: {}
}, {
    _id: "3d0c4375",
    userid: "LqDuEwgv",
    time: 1584353953159,
    content: {}
}, {
    _id: "574ee87",
    userid: "LqDuEwgv",
    time: 1584353953159,
    content: {}
}, {
    _id: "Pcs93S4R9v",
    userid: "KqDuEwgv",
    time: 1584353953159,
    content: {}
}]
```

I want the output to be like

```
[{
    _id: "Kcs93S4R9v",
    userid: "KqDuEwgv",
    time: 1584353953159,
    content: [{}, {}]
}, {
        _id: "574ee87",
        userid: "LqDuEwgv",
        time: 1584353953159,
        content: [{}, {}]
}]
```

But I can't seem to figure it out. Is there any way to do this with MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$group` operator in aggregation. Like below:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$userid",
      time: {
        $first: "$time"
      },
      content: {
        $push: "$content"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayGroundLink](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uzSRw6-Wrex)

**Edit:**
To first match the documents with the `time` field, you can use the `$match` operator,

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      time: 1584353953159
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$userid",
      time: {
        $first: "$time"
      },
      content: {
        $push: "$content"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: and what to do if I have to make this query based on time, like find the users in a particular timestamp?

Comment: You mean find the users in a particular time and then group them like above?

Comment: Yes, exactly this is required.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you need to use `$match` operator.